# How to have a sticky navbar in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My navbar is hiding the contents below the navbar. Also, it's sticked to  the left side instead of the middle part. I hope someone could show me the right way to make the navbar right way to make a sticky navbar that stays in its place even when we are scrolling.

code sanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-voice-24udr

Navbar.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const NavbarPage = () => {
  const guestLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button className="btn btn-primary createNew">Create New</Button>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">
          <Button className="btn btn-danger signOut">Sign out</Button>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
  return (
    <nav className="navbar bg-white">
      <h3 className="titleName">
        <Link to="/">
          <i className="fas fa-pen" /> demo
        </Link>
      </h3>
      {guestLinks}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavbarPage;
```

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 88.15%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0.9;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

just wondering you can use `position: sticky; top: 0` to do the same thing.

Pure CSS will be faster

Answer (score 4):

```
<Navbar sticky="top" />
```

Look at
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Comment: I'm not using Navbar. Can I still incorporate this with my existing navbar code

Answer (score 1):

#### make these changes in your CSS

```css
.navbar {
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%; 
      margin: auto;
      top: 0;
      border-bottom: solid 1px var(--primary-color);
      opacity: 0.9;

      position: fixed;
      top: 0;

      /* box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); */
      box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
        -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
      box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
        12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
        -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
    }

.conMain {
  height: 130vh;
  margin-top: 100px; //you need to add margin for your layout main 
  container
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it is not working. you can see my updated code sandbox

Comment: 1 min ill check

Comment: Yeah it's showing the contents below but I don't want the width to be 100% but same as my body contents which is 88%. If I change the width to 88% then it goes to the left side and not in the middle, and the bottom box-shadow disappeared too. Can you help me fix it

Comment: you need to improve your CSS.please check w3schools website where you can find your all solutions.if you need more help then ping me ok

Comment: the width is working but the bottom shadow is not there

Comment: and please right this answer if you are getting help from it.

Comment: let me know if you need any help. I am happy to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199960/discussion-between-henrydoe-and-prakash-karena).

Answer (score 0):

This works for React components too:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me -

```
position: fixed;

top: 0;
```